# How to execute Google Glass In Mobile Device Without Using Glass

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-glass

I need to develop a sample basic Hello World app for google glass, but don't have glass.
I got to know that app can also install and test it on device.

What are the pre-requirements to develop it. Please let me know there is any sample code.

I have Samsung Galaxy S2 and Lenovo Tab.

If any one have idea how to start than please give some guide.

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start read official document

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up Glass On mobile or an Emulator in Web. Gooogle Glass is orignally a launcher over android you need to install the apks of that launcher.

**[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2298214)** you will find the APK's  (**however Camera for Glass never worked for me.**)

**[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vObAJ.jpg)** is an Album showing you the process (on Nexus 7)

**[And This](https://github.com/harrywye/gdkdemo)** is the set of Demo's

After all set up you have to connect the android phone and then install the apk's using adb.
e.g.

```
adb install -r com.sample.packagee
```

after that you can launch the app through voice command or if it doesnot support voice trigger then launch it like

```
adb shell am start -n com.mikedg.android.glass.launchy/.MainActivity
```

**I am writing down a wiki for the issues and the to do's [Please check it here](http://jumpstartpakistan.com/wiki/wiki/3/google-glass).**.

Comment: I havent added alot of things in wiki so let me know if you need anything else.. :)